# Twin paradox with entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

2 bundles of electrons, bundle 1(even indexed electrons) bundle 2(odd indexed electrons) not important how I label them.

Bundle 1 remains on Earth doing double slit while bundle 2 is doing double slit on a relativistic missile traveling at 0.99c towards voyager 1.

We shall agreed that both must shows interference pattern.

Next we entangle bundle 1 electrons with photon, p1 and bundle 2 electrons with photon p2.

Current distance between bundle 1 and bundle 2 is more than 1 light seconds.

If I placed a detector at one of the slit for bundle 1, now bundle 1 is not showing interference pattern. At this instant p1 is entangled with p2... would bundle 2 immediately collapse too?

Comment: What is your method to entangle the electrons with the photons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entanglement is a property of wave functions of more than one particle, it really does not care whether one part of your system is stationary and the other part is moving relativistically. From your description, it is not clear that anything interesting will happen because you did not say whether the first bundle of electrons was initially entangled with the second bundle. If there are not then the experiments are completely independent and no interesting phenomenon will occur.

You could decided to entangle the two bundles by using photons i.e we have two entangled photons, one of them interacts with the first bundle of electrons while the second photon interacts with the second bundle of electrons. In order to see entanglement in electron path you have to make the interactions of the helicity of the photon is connected with the "which way information of the electron" in such a way that observing the electron going through one slit is tied with the specific helicity of the photon and thus giving you information about the "which way information" of the second bundle of electrons. None of this would care about whether the one bundle is next to the other, is on andromeda galaxy or moving relativistically.

Secondly, the point of the twin paradox is that it is not really a paradox and you are not obeying the assumptions of special relativity. So there is no reason why you would mention the twin paradox to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that if you are dealing with subatomic particles you have to consider the Heisenberg uncertainty principle as well.

I think that entanglement and the twins paradox are two separate entities formed by two separate branches of physics.